# IPV6 crash iOS, can't figure out whats going on

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-ec2

```
func getData() {
    let myURLString = "http://ec2-54-201-235-38.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/"+Hot+".php?radius=15&curr_time="+noww+"lat="+String(lat)+"&long="+String(long)
    print(myURLString)
    let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString)!
    var myCardsArray = [Card]()
    let mySession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let myDataTask = mySession.dataTaskWithURL(myURL) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
        //do stuff with the data that comes out of this
    }
}
```

So this code makes a URL session and gets data and puts it in an array. All that works so I left it out. When I submitted the app, I found that it crashes on IPV6 only networks and have no idea why. I'm using NSURLSession so it should be fine?

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because AWS EC2 does not support IPV6 that is the reason it is crashing on IPV6 networks. You will have to integrate that EC2 instance through AWS Elastic Load Balancer as AWS ELB supports IPV6.

Check this documentation.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancing-ipv6-zone-apex-support-additional-security/